# How do I use str_replace with a search array and replace it with part of the search array that was found?

Tags: php, laravel, str-replace

I am doing a str_replace with a search array and I want to replace it with a string that includes the value in the array that was found.

This is my search array

```
$search_array = array("**JOB DESCRIPTION1**","**JOB DESCRIPTION2**","**JOB DESCRIPTION3**");
```

This is my string

```
$string = "**JOB DESCRIPTION1** does this objective, and **JOB DESCRIPTION2** does this."
```

I want to replace it with a button that says "Click here to replace JOB DESCRIPTION1".

I am trying something like this, but it fails.

```
$new_string = str_replace($search_array,'<button>Click here to replace '.$search_array.'</button>',$string)
```

Comment: you should use regular expressions

Comment: Yes, preg_replace() seems like a good tool for this.